# Why doesn't my legend appear when drawing geom_sf with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm following [this guide](https://rpubs.com/valentin/pacific-centered-map-voronoi-tessellation) to create some dots on a map. It all works great but I can't produce a legend for the dots. I'm just going to copy the code to get a MWE (but all credit goes to Valentin Stefan):

```
library(rgeos)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

theme_set(
  theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "azure"),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 8))
)

world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 'medium', returnclass = "sp")
box_cut <- bbox2SP(n = 90, s = -90, w = -70, e = 120, proj4string = world@proj4string)
world_crop <- gDifference(world, box_cut)

pacific_crop <- world_crop %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% # change from sp to sf object/class
  st_shift_longitude() %>% 
  st_crop(c(xmin = st_bbox(.)[["xmin"]],
            xmax = st_bbox(.)[["xmax"]],
            ymin = -50,
            ymax = 30))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pacific_crop)

tiny_countries <- rnaturalearthdata::tiny_countries50 %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_shift_longitude() %>% 
  st_crop(c(xmin = 120, xmax = 250, ymin = -50, ymax = 30)) %>% 
  # Also adds the coordinates to be used for labeling with geom_text_repel
  bind_cols(st_coordinates(.) %>% as.data.frame())

rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))

Col <- rbPal(18)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pacific_crop) +
  geom_sf(data = tiny_countries, size = 2, color = Col, show.legend = "point")
```

How can I get a legend for color?

I've tried, without success, changing the position of the legend:

```
theme(legend.position = c(.5,.5))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A legend is created in `ggplot2` when one or more columns in your dataset are mapped via `aes()` to one of the aesthetic modifiers (for example, `fill`, `shape`, `size`, `color`, `alpha`...).  In your plot code, you are specifying a list of color values, but `ggplot2` has no idea what that should be linked to in your data.  Consequently, the colors are mapped according to the observations in your data frame `tiny_countries` line by line, without actually generating a link between your data and the color.

When you put `color` inside `aes()`, you indicate this modifier should be mapped to a particular column in your data.  `ggplot2` will then assign colors to each "different" value in your dataframe.  If you just want `ggplot2` to specify each tiny country is a different color, then, you need to pick a label for each country.  We would naturally want the label to correspond to the name, since... that makes sense, so we would create the mapping via `aes(color=name)`.

Note that *this does not specify the color*.  Be default, `ggplot2` will use it's default coloring scheme, but as you have already specified a list of proper number of values for the color... we can tell `ggplot2` we want to override the default coloring and use your own specific colors manually.  We do that using a `scale_*_manual()` function, where `*` corresponds to the particular aesthetic modifier in question.  Putting this together you get this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = pacific_crop) +
  geom_sf(data = tiny_countries, aes(color=name), size = 2, show.legend = "point") +
  scale_color_manual(values=Col) +
  theme(legend.position='bottom')  # thought the legend looks best on the bottom
```

[image]

Comment: As a follow up, how could you move this legend into the plotting space, instead of into the margin? As OP pointed out theme(legend.position = c(x, y)) does not seem to work.